# Seeking spatialized Employment Information for England?

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, uk, europe

I was looking for a shapefile with employment opportunities (jobs) for England or London – at the LSOA or output level. Im not sure is this is what they call Workplace population.

Is this it? 
Do you know how to get the data?

Comment: The [Office for National Statistics website](http://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/articles/workplacepopulationanalysis/2014-05-23) suggests the workplace population is merely an estimate of the "population whose usual place of work is in that local authority, including both individuals who live and work in the local authority and individuals who work in the local authority but commute from a home elsewhere within England or Wales".

Comment: The [UK government data portal](https://data.gov.uk/data/search?q=employment) portal gives 903 results for datasets relating to Employment, so perhaps you may be able to find something of interest from there